# How to improve iterating performance in python

Tags: python, performance

I'm curious about such low performance of python engine in loop iteration. I have tested the same algorithm on nodejs, php and python. Here are code snippets and results

test.php:

```
<?php
    $t1 = time();

    for($i = 1; $i < 50000; $i++){
        $v = 1;
        for($j = 1; $j < 50000; $j++){

        }
    }

    $t2 = time();

    echo $t2 - $t1;
```

test.js:

```
let t1 = Date.now()

for(let i = 1; i < 50000; i++){
    let v = 1
    for(let j = 1; j < 50000; j++){

    }
}

let t2 = Date.now()
console.log(t2 - t1)
```

test.py:

```
import time

t1 = int(time.time())

L1 = list(range(50000))
L2 = list(range(50000))

for x in L1:
    z = 1
    for y in L2:
        pass

t2 = int(time.time())
print(t2 - t1)
```

results:

> node test.js
>   1640 (1.6 seconds)
>
> php test.php
>   27 (27 seconds)
>
> python3 test.py
>   107 (107 seconds)

Comment: Why did you convert the `range` objects to lists? Why is the Python version doing an additions in the inner and outer loops while the other two get one assignment? If you add a C version and a compiler eliminates the entire benchmarked section for having no effects, does that mean Node has poor performance that needs to be improved?

Comment: I also experienced this type of situation. Use` numpy` module in python which makes faster iteration.

Comment: Converting the `range` objects to `lists` is about double as fast on my machine! Generators are mostly good for saving on memory, but there is an overhead to using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @maxy answered, you can use numba to accelerate the for loop. The result of the following code is 0.07 on my computer.

```
import time
from numba import jit


@jit
def loop_test(num):
    a = 0
    for i in range(num):
        for j in range(num):
            a += 1
    return a


def main():
    t1 = time.time()
    ret = loop_test(50000)
    t2 = time.time()
    print(t2 - t1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Nice, but be careful with the numbers; if you just `return num*num` it doesn't get much faster. (Loop probably got optimized away.)

Answer (score 2):

Python is mostly interpreted byte-code, while javascript gets compiled to machine-code by the JIT. As an (very unreliable) order of magnitude, Python is ~100x slower in microbenchmarks than C/C++/Rust, while Java and Javascript are only ~3x slower. In reality it depends on the benchmark.

If you use Python the right way, e.g. use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) instead of iterating over each element for vector math, or just do stuff where you will be waiting for network I/O most of the time, you will never notice much performance difference.

It's also possible to accelerate numeric Python code with [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) or [cython](https://cython.org/) or a C module just for the critical part of your code. But usually it's better to use Python to glue existing optimized libraries together.